# Magento 2 apply tax class programmatically to customer

Tags: magento2, checkout, tax, tax-class

I want to add the customs tax based on the selection of shipping method.

We have created the tax rule and rate on admin panel and assigned that to customs tax class.

I want to assign that custom tax rule to the customer.Is there any possibility to assigned the tax rule programmatically on the checkout page.

Please help on the above issue.Any references and suggestion are highly appreciated.

Thanks.